# QGIS / QField: nested relational value form QGIS save refused QField

Tags: qfield, actions, save

The Field Survey project should have been operational for two days already, but I have a major problem.
After having succeeded in nested two fields in the form (relational value), we realize that the saving under QField is not done!

Where is the concern?
QGIS side, in the form? (group/detail interlocking is not active in update mode)
QField side? who if he does not know how to read the expression, does not want to take it into account?

I have attached several screenshots to understand my concern
Hope any of you can help me solve this blocking problem.

Additional info: I switch from QQGIS to QField by QField sync.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with qfield 1.8?

Comment: Hello,
I am using the latest version available on google play, (updated on 18 dec 2020). No version 1.8 proposed. Sorry

Comment: and QFieldSync 3.4.0 in QGis 3.16